# power (a, n) in PYTHON

Tags: python-3.x

POwer in Python. How to write code to display a ^ n using funсtion?
why doesn't this code working?

```
a = int(input())
n = int(input())

def power(a, n):
     for i in range (n):
        a=1
        a *= n


print(power (a, n))
```

Comment: 1. You keep resetting a to one. 2. You never return anything from the function

Comment: someone who deleted his post (takes courage since it was upvoted) suggested to simply use `a**n` to compute what you want. You can define power as `power = lambda a,n : a**n`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm sure lambdas and oneliners are all the rage in personal programming .. but would you really use that as an example of how python functions function?

Comment: @DavidLipnik I'm just saying: it's no use to reinvent a power function. But if you want to call it `power`, you can. And learn about `lambda`. Because even if you don't want to use it you'll stumble on some code using it all the time and you'll be lost. I was, until I made the effort looking that up (and listcomps)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I wholly agree the knowledge of the functionality is useful, not only in cases where you work with other people's code, but in cutting down time when coding too .. but for learning and explaining how python basics work  it's quite the opposite of mandatory - it's confusing and off-putting.

Comment: If you want to learn python I suggest training on math problems of project euler BTW.

Answer (score 2):

Few errors:

1. Changing `a` will lose your power parameter, use `result` (or something else).
2. Move setting `result = 1` **outside** your loop to do so once.
3. Multiply by `a` not by `n`.
4. Use `return` to return a value from the function

---

```
def power(a, n):
    result = 1 # 1 + 2
    for _ in range (n):
        result *= a # 3
    return result # 4
```

Style notes:

1. Setting/mutating a parameter is considered bad practice (unless explicitly needed), even if it is immutable as is here.
2. If you're not going to use the loop variable, you can let the reader know by using the conventional `_` to indicate it (`_` is a legal variable name, but it is conventional to use it when *not* needing the variable).

Tip: you can simple use `a**n`

Comment: And you should use a different variable than a for computation.

Comment: @macmoonshine matter of taste since a is not mutable, but I agree.

Comment: why are you iterating with `i` if you 're not gonna use it?

Comment: @Reut: But a is the name of a parameter which is needed for computation.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because your function doesn't return the end value. Add `return a` to the end of the function.

### ALSO:

That is not how `a` to the power of `n` is is calculated. 
A proper solution:

```
def power(a,n):
    pow_a = a
    if n is 0:
        return 1
    for _ in range(n-1): # Substracting 1 from the input variable n
        pow_a *= a       # because n==2 means a*a already.
    return pow_a
```

and if you want to be really cool, recursion is the way:

```
def power_recursive(a,n):
    if n is 0:
        return 1
    elif n is 1:
        return a
    else:
        a *= power_recursive(a,n-1)
    return a
```

Comment: A global variable isn't needed, but you must not use the same name for the parameter and the variable for result computation.

Comment: Are you claiming that:
`a = 10`
`def change_a(a): a *= 2`
`print(a)` prints 20?
(to be more verbose; the print happens outside the function)

Comment: No. You should not change the value of a whilst it's value is needed.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the explanation on global variables.

Comment: The missing return statement is not the only problem of the code.

Comment: I did point out his math doesn't add up? I've included large bold letters to express the importance of the added paragraph.. 

He didn't come here with a math problem though, but a python problem.

Comment: Rewriting the function that a contains the result is difficult. See Reut's answer.

Comment: I've added a working solution to my answer. Please PM for further questions, lets not trash up the comment section.

Comment: You change the parameter a inside of the loop. This leads to a wrong result. See discussion of Reut's answer. Btw. I've removed my downvote. ;)